# Extracting e-mail address from a html structure using PHP

Tags: php, joomla-community-builder

I am trying to modify a php file (It is of Joomla extension `Community Builder 1.9.1`, and the file is `\components\com_comprofiler\plugin\templates\default\default.php`), in order to extract the e-mail address from a variable.

For description’s sake, let’s say this variable is `$html`. To make sure this variable is the right one containing the e-mail address that I'm targeting, I insert:

```
<pre><?php print_r($html) ?></pre>
```

Into the file, and its output is the email address with a mailto link, and the corresponding HTML is something like

```
<span id="cbMa47822" class="cbMailRepl"><a href="mailto:myemail@yahoo.com">myemail@yahoo.com</a></span>
```

So I guess I can use:

```
<?php $html_array = explode("\"",$html);echo $html_array[5]; ?>
```

Io get `'mailto:myemail@yahoo.com';` But actually it only returns a notice of:

> undefined offset:5

So I `print_r($html_array)`, and it return something like

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  cbMa14768
    [2] =>  class=
    [3] => cbMailRepl
    [4] => >... 
)
```

It looks like the `<a>` tag part of the html output is replaced by `"..."`, like what you see in Chrome’s developer tool html inspector, where before you expand it, the HTML looks like:

```
<span id="cbMa47822" class="cbMailRepl">...</span>
```

I looked deeper into the php code, trying to find out how this `$html` is contructed, but it is totally beyond my understanding.

For learning purpose, my questions are:

1. why there is no `[1]` in the result of `print_r($html_array)`
2. How do I test a variable’s value more exactly, by more exactly I mean totally without html input, like if the value is `"<a href="htt://foo.com">foo</a>"`, if should display the HTML as is, but not a link (when I use `print_r`, it returns a link)?
3. And most importantly, based on the information given above, can you give my any hint regarding how I can extract the e-mail address from a variable like this?

Finally, for those who are willing to take a deeper look into this, the variable I am talking about is `$this->tableContent[$userIdx][1][6]->value` in `\components\com_comprofiler\plugin\templates\default\default.php`, originally it wasn't in the code but I did some test and confirm it contains the email address. I inserted the following code between line 450 & 451

```
<?php $html_array = explode("\"",$this->tableContent[$userIdx][1][6]->value);echo $html_array[5]; ?>
```

Comment: Sir, your answer is fine and it does help me learn some new tricks. But concerning my original problem, here is some updates(I find out how to inspect a string value as is using `htmlspecialchars()`): if I `pring_r($html)`, it will output an email address with a mailto link, wrapped by a pair of span tag, as you can see in my main post. But if I `echo htmlspecialchars($html)`, it will only output `<span id="cbMa89484" class="cbMailRepl">...</span>`, the `<a>` tag containing the wanted email address is replaced by `...`. I can not understand how this is happening at all.

Answer (score 0):

To extract an e-mail address from an HTML strcuture as you describe, just use regex and [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match):

```
$html = '<span id="cbMa47822" class="cbMailRepl"><a href="mailto:myemail@yahoo.com">myemail@yahoo.com</a></span>';

preg_match("/mailto:(.*)\">/is", $html, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => mailto:myemail@yahoo.com">
    [1] => myemail@yahoo.com
)
```

So to access that e-mail address, just do this:

```
echo $matches[1];
```

The output would be:

```
myemail@yahoo.com
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your enlightening answer.
I tested the above code and it runs fine on local, but once I replace the $html variable with the actual one ($this->tableContent[$userIdx][1][6]->value) and insert the code into the file for testing, the output is
 
>Array
>(
>)

So I guess the problem is with how the variable was constructed. After all, if your code works with the actual file, my code using explode() should also have worked.

Comment: So now I think the question of mine is focusing on how to print a string value containing html strctures as is,instead of something already interpreted by th browser. Only then I can get a more accurate sense about what excatly $this->tableContent[$userIdx][1][6]->value contains and establish a way to extract email address from it thereafter.

Answer (score -1):

1. To avoid links you can use escape sequence.
2. you can use regular expression to match if the given string matches the email address     pattern and print it
3. PHP has a vast support for functions which can perform wierdest tasks so search for them

Comment: Thank you sir, could you please be more specific? Like if I have a string with the value of "<span><a href="http://foo.com">foo</a></span>", how can I get it to display the value as is but not something already interpreted by the browser(which will be "foo" with a link only)

Comment: I think a minor change in Jake's regex  preg_match("/<a href=mailto:(.*)\">(.*)</a>/", $html, $matches); it will work as it will return to you complete url <a href="foo.com">foo</a> another thing take care of escape sequence